# shell - grep - how to get only lines that have certain amount char

Tags: shell, grep

good morning.
I have the following lines :

```
1 | blah | 2 | 1993 | 86 | 0 | NA | 123 | 123
1 | blah | TheBeatles | 0 | 3058 | NA | NA | 11
```

And I wanna get only the lines with 7 `"|"` and the same first field.

So the output for these two lines will be nothing, but for these two lines :

```
1 | blah | 2 | 1993 | 86 | 0 | NA | 123 
1 | blah | TheBeatles | 0 | 3058 | NA | NA | 11
```

The output will be "error". 
I'm getting the inputs from a file using the following command :

```
grep '.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*|.*' < $1 | sort -nbsk1 | cut -d "|" -f1 | uniq -d |
while read line2; do
  echo error
done
```

But this implementation would still print error even if I have more then 7 "|". 
Any suggestions ?

P.S - I can assume that there is a \n in the end of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `grep`

```
grep '^\([^|]*|[^|]*\)\{7\}$'
```

Answer (score 2):

For printing lines containing only 7 `|`, try:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF == 8' filename
```

If you want to use bash to count the number of `|` in a given line, try:

```
line="1 | blah | 2 | 1993 | 86 | 0 | NA | 123 | 123";
count=${line//[^|]/};
echo ${#count};
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use awk :\ same for sed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `zz.txt` is:

```
$ cat zz.txt

1 | blah | 2 | 1993 | 86 | 0 | NA | 123 | 123
1 | blah | TheBeatles | 0 | 3058 | NA | NA | 11
```

---

```
$ cut  -d\| -f1-8 zz.txt
```

above `cut` will give you the output you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use awk for this job.

```
BEGIN { FS = "|" }
NF == 8 && $1 == '1' { print $0}
```

would do the job (although the == and && could be = and & ; my awk is a bit rusty)

Comment: If there are 7 separators, then there are 8 fields. Your syntax is correct

Comment: I spoke too soon: `NF` is the number of fields; `$NF` is the *value* of the last field